# Refactoring JS function to target multiple ids

Tags: javascript

I have four boxes on a page that I want to change colour when a user clicks on them. I gave each box an id:

```
<div id="boxa" onclick="changeColorA()"></div>
<div id="boxb" onclick="changeColorB()"></div>
<div id="boxc" onclick="changeColorC()"></div>
<div id="boxd" onclick="changeColorD()"></div>
```

As you can see, in order to change the box color using onclick, I've had to write a separate function for each box:

```
function changeColorA() {
  var col = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
  document.getElementById("boxa").style.backgroundColor=col;
}

function changeColorB() {
  var col = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
  document.getElementById("boxb").style.backgroundColor=col;
}

function changeColorC() {
  var col = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
  document.getElementById("boxc").style.backgroundColor=col;
}

function changeColorD() {
  var col = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
  document.getElementById("boxd").style.backgroundColor=col;
}
```

I've run this in the browser on an iPad and it's running too slow. How can I refactor this so that I have just one function that targets any box a user clicks on?

```js
function changeColorA() {
  var col = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  document.getElementById("boxa").style.backgroundColor = col;
}

function changeColorB() {
  var col = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  document.getElementById("boxb").style.backgroundColor = col;
}

function changeColorC() {
  var col = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  document.getElementById("boxc").style.backgroundColor = col;
}

function changeColorD() {
  var col = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  document.getElementById("boxd").style.backgroundColor = col;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 758px;
  height: 1014px;
}

#main {
  background-color: #00b894;
  width: 748px;
  height: 1004px;
}

.container-1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.container-2 {
  text-align: center;
}

#boxa {
  margin-top: 250px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fab1a0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#boxb {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #00cec9;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#boxc {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #55efc4;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#boxd {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #6c5ce7;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxa" onclick="changeColorA()"></div>
<div id="boxb" onclick="changeColorB()"></div>
<div id="boxc" onclick="changeColorC()"></div>
<div id="boxd" onclick="changeColorD()"></div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/simonrevill/pen/WzZReX

Comment: Work with classes instead.

Comment: Use parameters, `changeColor(idName)` `document.getElementById(idName)` or  use the keyword `this`

Comment: Would the slowness not come from `Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)` rather than multiple click events being bound? Using a single function might not fix the slowness in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```js
function changeColor(element) {
  var col = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  element.style.backgroundColor = col;
}
```

```css
#boxa {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fab1a0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#boxb {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #00cec9;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#boxc {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #55efc4;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#boxd {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #6c5ce7;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxa" onclick="changeColor(this)"></div>
<div id="boxb" onclick="changeColor(this)"></div>
<div id="boxc" onclick="changeColor(this)"></div>
<div id="boxd" onclick="changeColor(this)"></div>
```

Comment: This is a very simple solution, thanks. Works great on Chrome etc, but it is still running quite slow on the iPad (using Dolphin app to access full screen viewing). The colors change but not as instantly as I would like. Any ideas on how to improve performance? Here's the new code: https://codepen.io/simonrevill/pen/WzZReX

Comment: actually, don't worry. performance is fine on ipad in chrome and safari.

Comment: @SimonRevill, you are most welcome. Great to know that the answer is helpful to you....thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can assign a common class the attach event listener using `addEventListener()` method. In the event listener `this` refers to the element which invoke the  event handler

```js
function changeColor() {
  var col = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  this.style.backgroundColor = col;
}

var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++)
  boxes[i].addEventListener('click', changeColor)
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 758px;
  height: 1014px;
}

#main {
  background-color: #00b894;
  width: 748px;
  height: 1004px;
}

.container-1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.container-2 {
  text-align: center;
}

#boxa {
  margin-top: 250px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fab1a0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#boxb {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #00cec9;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#boxc {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #55efc4;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#boxd {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #6c5ce7;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="boxa"></div>
<div class="box" id="boxb"></div>
<div class="box" id="boxc"></div>
<div class="box" id="boxd"></div>
```

References

1. [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
2. [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: Not as important side-note to OP and it probably doesn't apply but just in case OP works in a place where UIX has their own team. Try to replace classes with attributes or your code might stop working for no reason after the next UIX update or styles might stop working when you change your code and UIX used your class :) - Happened to us a lot, so we left classes for styles only and attributes for functional code.

Answer (score -1):

To handle multiple `click` events in `divs', you can simplify your code by making use of`event delegation`.

Just add a parent div `#box` and add an `event listener` to it. When you click on any of the `child divs`, the event will get delegated to the `parent` div and you can make use of `event.target` to change the color.

```js
var box = document.getElementById("box");

box.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  var col = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
  event.target.style.backgroundColor=col;
});
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="boxa">A</div>
  <div id="boxb">B</div>
  <div id="boxc">C</div>
  <div id="boxd">D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is unreliable and not really addressing the issue head-on as any other click event from any future element added into that div will also trigger the click event. Then you have to keep maintaining the code to ensure you check what was clicked etc, etc,... It also adds another wrapper element which was not needed before possibly impacting existing UI design/layout.

Comment: Event delegation is a preferred way instead of adding multiple events in multiple divs. The simple solution to the points regarding scalability you are making can be simply handled in the function. The requirement to add or not add a  wrapper element is design choice. This code increases performance as you don't have to access multiple divs.

Comment: Not sure Event delegation is a preferred solution over a single event handler. I think Event Delegation is very specific and not to be used lightly as it adds overhead in itself. Though, off course, while I don't agree with it in this case doesn't mean it isn't the best solution for this issue.

Comment: In the question, OP is using multiple event handlers (one each for four divs). Hence for the question, I would prefer to use event delegation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am still learning JS, and have not used event listeners yet. However I can understand the logic of targeting the container div, then the specific div within, all with a single function. I will try and refactor the code in this way now.